# Mimic functionality of "Download" link via Git cli

Tags: git, branch, bitbucket-server

I have a git repo. In the left nav, there's an option to "Download". It downloads the master branch as a zip file. How do I do the same thing via the cli?

For some reason, when I use git clone, the data that it returns is not the same. I only know this because said data is ran through a Java program and the output is different depending on how it's pulled from git. I have tried getting this data lots of ways and the only way that works is manually downloading it from the GUI.

EDIT:
Maybe a better way to ask this is: What command is being ran when I click the "Download" link?

EDIT 2: @Arkadiusz Drabczyk's solution in the comments of the "cliget" add-on in Firefox was a perfect solution. Much appreciated.

Comment: What operating system do you use? On `*nix` (`Linux`) for example you could use `wget`.

Comment: I could use wget, but I can't get the URL for the "Download" link. When I hover over it, if try to wget that URL, it's not equivalent to pressing the download button. It's like a redirect and I just wget a webpage essentially, rather than a zip

Comment: Are you sure you use `github` because in `github` the `Clone or download` button is on the *right* side?

Comment: I'm actually using an internally hosted version of Stash; is the functionality that different?

Comment: Yes, I think it's different. Consider this: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cliget/. I use it and can recommend it. It's an addon for generating `curl` commands, it automatically handles cookies etc. so I think it might be what you looking for. I just tried it on my account on `bitbucket` and it generated a `curl` command together with `Cookie:` part which allowed me to download a `.zip` file on behalf of the logged-in user from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

To get the content of a revision (say, the tip of a given branch... but it could be any other revision) on a zip file (say, some_zip_file.zip):

`git archive --format=zip -o some_zip_file.zip master`

Comment: Thanks. Do I have to have git cloned that repo first?

Comment: Yep... if you only care about getting a single revision and you don't want to have a full clone of the repo, then do a shallow clone to be able to get the revision you want https://www.perforce.com/blog/141218/git-beyond-basics-using-shallow-clones